# Parsing XML with XElement results in Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

The XML below is being returned from a web service.  However, I cannot seem to get the value of  or  when using XElement.

```
<ResponseArray xmlns="urn:mdWebServiceAddress" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Version>2.0.62</Version>
  <TransmissionReference></TransmissionReference>
  <Results></Results>
  <TotalRecords>1</TotalRecords>
  <Record>
    <RecordID>1</RecordID>
    <Results>AC01,AS01</Results>
    <Address>
      <Address1>22382 Avenida Empresa</Address1>
      <Address2></Address2>
      <Suite></Suite>
      <PrivateMailBox></PrivateMailBox>
      <City>
        <Name>Rancho Santa Margarita</Name>
        <Abbreviation>Rcho Sta Marg</Abbreviation>
      </City>
      <State>
        <Name>California</Name>
        <Abbreviation>CA</Abbreviation>
      </State>
      <Zip>92688</Zip>
      <Plus4>2112</Plus4>
      <AddressKey>92688211282</AddressKey>
    </Address>
  </Record>
</ResponseArray>
```

Below is the code I am using to collect the values.  Is the namespace being set incorrectly?  How do I access the values of these elements in the XML.

```
        XElement xelement = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

        IEnumerable<XElement> records = xelement.Elements();

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(record.Element(ns + "RecordID").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(record.Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "AddressKey").Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) change namespace

b) use Descendants

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:mdWebServiceAddress";

IEnumerable<XElement> records = xelement.Descendants(ns + "Record");

foreach (var record in records)
{
    Console.WriteLine(record.Element(ns + "RecordID").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(record.Element(ns + "Address").Element(ns + "AddressKey").Value);
}
```

PS: *Safe way to use xml namespaces can be*

```
XNamespace ns = xelement.GetDefaultNamespace();
```